# Finding contour of hand from a frame of video

Tags: opencv, contour

I am working on a project to recognize sign language using real time video analytics. I am stuck with finding contour for detecting hand from the video frame.
 I did convert my frame to gray scale, found the contour points but still confused how to draw a contour for hand out of image. I did see some of the code preferably written in C++ but I getting confused( I want to write code in python).

Please be gentle with me, since I am new to openCV and don't know much of contours.

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    #fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(history=1, varThreshold=30)
aWeight = 0.5
top, right, bottom, left = 10, 250, 425, 650
while(1):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=700)
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    clone = frame.copy()
    (height, width) = frame.shape[:2]
    roi = frame[top:bottom, right:left]

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)

    #hsv = cv2.cvtColor(roi,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,0)
    contour,_ = cv2.findContours(gray,  cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    edges = cv2.Canny(gray,100,200)
    print(contour) 
    cv2.drawContours(frame,contour,-1,(0,255,0),3)
```

I am getting nothing with the images as the output of cv2.imshow() is just the images which we obtain from canny detection.

Comment: findContours returns 3 values, you code currently has 2. Also, the findContours should be done on the thresholded image. So your code should be `_, contour, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)`. Can you try this? Could you also post an image of `thresh`?

Comment: Nice to have one/some example image you are working on.

Comment: @Abhishek Thakur what version of OpenCV did you use? @J.D. since OpenCV 4.0, `findContours` only returns 2 values.